# Creating new variables with purrr (how does one go about that?)

Tags: r, purrr, dplyr

I have a large data set, with a bunch of columns that I want to run the same function on, based on either prefix or suffix, to create a new variable.

What I would like to be able to do is provide a list to map, and create new variables.

---

```
dataframe <- data_frame(x_1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                        x_2 = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                        y_1 = c(200,400,120,300,100,100),
                        y_2 = c(250,500,150,240,140,400))

newframe <- dataframe %>% mutate(x_ratio = x_1/x_2,
                                 y_ratio = y_1/y_2)
```

---

In the past, i have written code in a string something like

```
code <- "df <- df %>% mutate(#_ratio = #_1/#_2)" %>% str_replace_all("#",c("x","y"))
eval(parse(text=code)))
```

Is it possible with something along the lines of:
newframe <- dataframe %>% map(c("x","y"), mutate( paste0(.x,"_ratio)=paste0(.x,"_1/",.x,"_2))

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you saying that you want to run the same function on each pair of columns? Or will the function vary depending on the column names?

Comment: Same function.  Sometimes I need to multiply numbers, sometimes divide.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to use `map`, then one option is to `split` the dataset by the column names and divide with `reduce`

```
library(tidyverse)
split.default(dataframe, sub("_\\d+", "", names(dataframe))) %>%
     map_df(., reduce, `/`) %>% 
       rename_all(~ paste0(.x, "_ratio")) %>%
       bind_cols(dataframe, .)
```