# How can I use map* and mutate to convert a list into a set of additional columns?

Tags: r, purrr, dplyr, tidyeval

I have tried probably hundreds of permutations of this code for *literally days* to try to get a function that will do what I want, and I have finally given up. It feels like it should definitely be doable and I am so close!

I have tried to get back to the nub of things here with my reprex below.

Basically I have a single-row dataframe, with <strike>a column containing</strike> a list of strings ("concepts"). I want to create an additional column for each of those strings, using `mutate`, ideally with the column taking its name from the string, and then to populate the column with the results of a function call (?it doesn't matter which function, for now? - I just need the infrastructure of the function to work.)

I feel, as usual, like I must be missing something obvious... maybe just a syntax error.
I also wonder if I need to use `purrr::map`, maybe a simpler vectorised mapping would work fine.

I feel like the fact that new columns are named `..1` rather than the concept name is a bit of a clue as to what is wrong.

I can create the data frame I want by calling each concept manually (see end of reprex) but since the list of concepts is different for different data frames, I want to functionalise this using pipes and tidyverse techniques rather than do it manually.

I've read the following questions to find help:

- [How to use map from purrr with dplyr::mutate to create multiple new columns based on column pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816669/how-to-use-map-from-purrr-with-dplyrmutate-to-create-multiple-new-columns-base)
- [How to mutate multiple columns with dynamic variable using purrr:map function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57183024/how-to-mutate-multiple-columns-with-dynamic-variable-using-purrrmap-function)
- [(R) Cleaner way to use map() with list-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53938745/r-cleaner-way-to-use-map-with-list-columns)
- [Add multiple output variables using purrr and a predefined function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51978138/add-multiple-output-variables-using-purrr-and-a-predefined-function)
- [Creating new variables with purrr (how does one go about that?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52607511/creating-new-variables-with-purrr-how-does-one-go-about-that)
- [How to compute multiple new columns in a R dataframe with dynamic names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58641327/how-to-compute-multiple-new-columns-in-a-r-dataframe-with-dynamic-names)

but none of those has quite helped me crack the problem I'm experiencing. [*edit:* added in last q to that list which may be the technique I need].

```
<!-- language-all: lang-r -->


    # load packages -----------------------------------------------------------

    library(rlang)
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    library(magrittr)
    library(purrr)
    library(nomisr)



    # set up initial list of tibbles ------------------------------------------

    df <- list(
      district_population = tibble(
        dataset_title = "Population estimates - local authority based by single year",
        dataset_id = "NM_2002_1"
      ),
      jsa_claimants = tibble(
        dataset_title = "Jobseeker\'s Allowance with rates and proportions",
        dataset_id = "NM_1_1"
      )
    )


    # just use the first tibble for now, for testing --------------------------
    # ideally I want to map across dfs through a list -------------------------

    df <- df[[1]]

    # nitty gritty functions --------------------------------------------------

    get_concept_list <- function(df) {
      dataset_id <- pluck(df, "dataset_id")
      nomis_overview(id = dataset_id,
                     select = c("dimensions", "codes")) %>%
        pluck("value", 1, "dimension") %>%
        filter(!concept == "geography") %>%
        pull("concept")
    }

    # get_concept_list() returns the strings I need:
    get_concept_list(df)
    #> [1] "time"     "gender"   "c_age"    "measures"

    # Here is a list of examples of types of map* that do various things,
    # none of which is what I need it to do
    # I'm using toupper() here for simplicity - ultimately I will use
    # get_concept_info() to populate the new columns

    # this creates four new tibbles
    get_concept_list(df) %>% 
      map(~ mutate(df, {{.x}} := toupper(.x)))
    #> [[1]]
    #> # A tibble: 1 x 3
    #>   dataset_title                                               dataset_id ..1  
    #>   <chr>                                                       <chr>      <chr>
    #> 1 Population estimates - local authority based by single year NM_2002_1  TIME 
    #> 
    #> [[2]]
    #> # A tibble: 1 x 3
    #>   dataset_title                                               dataset_id ..1   
    #>   <chr>                                                       <chr>      <chr> 
    #> 1 Population estimates - local authority based by single year NM_2002_1  GENDER
    #> 
    #> [[3]]
    #> # A tibble: 1 x 3
    #>   dataset_title                                               dataset_id ..1  
    #>   <chr>                                                       <chr>      <chr>
    #> 1 Population estimates - local authority based by single year NM_2002_1  C_AGE
    #> 
    #> [[4]]
    #> # A tibble: 1 x 3
    #>   dataset_title                                               dataset_id ..1    
    #>   <chr>                                                       <chr>      <chr>  
    #> 1 Population estimates - local authority based by single year NM_2002_1  MEASUR~

    # this throws an error
    get_concept_list(df) %>% 
      map_chr(~ mutate(df, {{.x}} := toupper(.x)))
    #> Error: Result 1 must be a single string, not a vector of class `tbl_df/tbl/data.frame` and of length 3

    # this creates three extra rows in the tibble
    get_concept_list(df) %>% 
      map_df(~ mutate(df, {{.x}} := toupper(.x)))
    #> # A tibble: 4 x 3
    #>   dataset_title                                               dataset_id ..1    
    #>   <chr>                                                       <chr>      <chr>  
    #> 1 Population estimates - local authority based by single year NM_2002_1  TIME   
    #> 2 Population estimates - local authority based by single year NM_2002_1  GENDER 
    #> 3 Population estimates - local authority based by single year NM_2002_1  C_AGE  
    #> 4 Population estimates - local authority based by single year NM_2002_1  MEASUR~

    # this does the same as map_df
    get_concept_list(df) %>% 
      map_dfr(~ mutate(df, {{.x}} := toupper(.x)))
    #> # A tibble: 4 x 3
    #>   dataset_title                                               dataset_id ..1    
    #>   <chr>                                                       <chr>      <chr>  
    #> 1 Population estimates - local authority based by single year NM_2002_1  TIME   
    #> 2 Population estimates - local authority based by single year NM_2002_1  GENDER 
    #> 3 Population estimates - local authority based by single year NM_2002_1  C_AGE  
    #> 4 Population estimates - local authority based by single year NM_2002_1  MEASUR~

    # this creates a single tibble 12 columns wide
    get_concept_list(df) %>% 
      map_dfc(~ mutate(df, {{.x}} := toupper(.x)))
    #> # A tibble: 1 x 12
    #>   dataset_title dataset_id ..1   dataset_title1 dataset_id1 ..11  dataset_title2
    #>   <chr>         <chr>      <chr> <chr>          <chr>       <chr> <chr>         
    #> 1 Population e~ NM_2002_1  TIME  Population es~ NM_2002_1   GEND~ Population es~
    #> # ... with 5 more variables: dataset_id2 <chr>, ..12 <chr>,
    #> #   dataset_title3 <chr>, dataset_id3 <chr>, ..13 <chr>

    # function to get info on each concept (except geography) -----------------
    # this is the function I want to use eventually to populate my new columns

    get_concept_info <- function(df, concept_name) {
      dataset_id <- pluck(df, "dataset_id")
      nomis_overview(id = dataset_id) %>%
        filter(name == "dimensions") %>%
        pluck("value", 1, "dimension") %>%
        filter(concept == concept_name) %>%
        pluck("codes.code", 1) %>%
        select(name, value) %>%
        nest(data = everything()) %>%
        as.list() %>%
        pluck("data")
    }


    # individual mutate works, for comparison ---------------------------------
    # I can create the kind of table I want manually using a line like the one below

    # df %>% map(~ mutate(., measures = get_concept_info(., concept_name = "measures")))
    df %>% mutate(., measures = get_concept_info(df, "measures"))
    #> # A tibble: 1 x 3
    #>   dataset_title                                        dataset_id measures      
    #>   <chr>                                                <chr>      <list>        
    #> 1 Population estimates - local authority based by sin~ NM_2002_1  <tibble [2 x ~

<sup>Created on 2020-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
```

Comment: It looks to me like this thread will have the answer to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58641327/how-to-compute-multiple-new-columns-in-a-r-dataframe-with-dynamic-names?rq=1

I'm just having a look through it now...

Comment: I just posted an answer, but I wasn't sure what you wanted for the output.  If that's not right, can you clarify what you want for output?

Comment: Perfect @EugeneChong thank you!

Comment: Nice!  I'm adding some more detail to the answer.

Comment: I was trying to get it using curly-curly but maybe that complicated things.

Comment: I should have posted on here some days ago instead of going through purgatory trying to find the right technique :-)
That reduce + left_join is neat. I did experiment with reduce() but didn't work it out. Have used map() before but not reduce(). It's good to learn.

Comment: The `{{ }}` does seem promising/usable, but I'm not sure how to implement it here. Perhaps someone else will offer a solution with that.  And I share your frustration with spending days doing this.  As it happens, I had the same struggle with this exact issue a while back, but it ended up being helpful for you today, and I'm sure you'll pass it on!

Comment: I will. I wrote it up in a gist: https://gist.github.com/francisbarton/aea23b429688033af96ba1df96988a8a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `!!` and `:=` lets you dynamically name columns.  Then, we can reduce the list output of `map()` with `reduce()`, which left_joins() all the dataframes in the list using the dataset title and id columns.

```r
df_2 <- 
  map(get_concept_list(df),
      ~ mutate(df,
               !!.x := get_concept_info(df, .x))) %>% 
  reduce(left_join, by = c("dataset_title", "dataset_id"))

df_2

# A tibble: 1 x 6
  dataset_title                                               dataset_id           time         gender          c_age       measures
  <chr>                                                       <chr>      <list<df[,2]>> <list<df[,2]>> <list<df[,2]>> <list<df[,2]>>
1 Population estimates - local authority based by single year NM_2002_1        [28 x 2]        [3 x 2]      [121 x 2]        [2 x 2]
```